# Converting BigDecimal ActiveRecord to Ruby string

Tags: ruby

I get a record from the DB like this:

```
@foo = Foo.find(params[:foo_id])
```

I need the whole `@foo` record but I need to use the `value` field in the ActiveRecord (of type BigDecimal).  I think I can do this (?):

```
 @val = @foo.value
```

but how do I convert `@val` to a string?  I found a `to_str` method but I get:

```
 undefined method `to_str' for #<BigDecimal:7f88d4e5fa10,'0.5155170589 999999E2',27(45)>
```

when I try and call `to_str` on `@val` like this:

```
 @val = @foo.value.to_str # ERROR here
```

Comment: `#to_str` is for implicit casts; BigDecimal doesn't support implicit casting to strings. `#to_s` is for explicit casts, as Michael noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `to_s` method which is standard method to convert any object to string in Ruby.

Comment: Thanks (again) Michael.  However, this is the original number: `51.55170589999999` and then after using `to_s`, I get `NTEuNTUxNzA1ODk5OTk5OTk=`

Comment: I wrote you should use to_s

Comment: Edited comment (sorry).. I did use `to_s`

Comment: irb(main):001:0> (51.55170589999999).to_s
=> "51.55170589999999"

Comment: This is impossible. The result you added is this value encoded with base64

Comment: See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html#method-i-to_s

Comment: It does work... I was doing `debug @val` which printed the base64 encoded value but `@val.inspect` printed the string.  Thanks for the help :).